# Pandas Google- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, pandas, search

I have stumbled upon a very strange case. I get the following error when I change the Google Search Console project, yet it worked perfectly with the previous (website) I used it for. Any idea why this might be? Thanks!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/k1/jt1nfyks4cx689d50f5mtg0w0000gp/T/ipykernel_1325/1849558386.py in <module>
     30 df = get_search_console_data(webproperty)
     31 
---> 32 df.head()
     33 df.info()
     34 df.to_csv("canadahelps.csv")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'


import searchconsole

import pandas as pd

account = searchconsole.authenticate(client_config='/Users/theodoredeliivanov/Downloads/client_fabbri.json', serialize='/Users/theodoredeliivanov/Downloads/credentials.json', flow="console")
account.webproperties
domain_name = "https://www.fabbriboutiques.com/it/"
webproperty = account[domain_name]


webproperty



#let's build a pandas dataframe with the search console data


def get_search_console_data(webproperty, days=-365): 
  if webproperty is not None:
    query = webproperty.query.range(start='today', days=days).dimension('date', 'query')
    r = query.get()
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.rows)
    return df

  print("Web property doesn't exist, please select a valid one from this list")
  print(account.webproperties)

  return None
   
df = get_search_console_data(webproperty) 

df.head()
df.info()
df.to_csv("canadahelps.csv")
```

Comment: You are returning None (`return None`) on the last line of your `get_search_console_data` function

Comment: so the webpropery does not exist? @Luke

Comment: I'm unable to tell if your returned object is `None` or if you are returning `None` by default

Comment: I don't think it is by default because it works with another `webproperty` @Luke